# hadoop mapper input deal with hex values

Tags: java, string, hadoop, unicode, utf-8

I have list of tweet as the input to the hdfs, and try to perform a map-reduce task. This is my mapper implementation:

```
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  try {
    String[] fields = value.toString().split("\t");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
      if (i > 1) {
        sb.append("\t");
      }
      sb.append(fields[i]);
    }
    tid.set(fields[0]);
    content.set(sb.toString());
    context.write(tid, content);
  } catch(DecoderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

As you can see, I tried to split the input by "\t", but the input (value.toString()) looks like this when I print it out:

```
2014\x091880284777\x09argento_un\x090\x090\x09RT @topmusic619: #RETWEET THIS!!!!!\x5CnFOLLOW ME &amp
; EVERYONE ELSE THAT RETWEETS THIS FOR 35+ FOLLOWERS\x5Cn#TeamFollowBack #Follow2BeFollowed #TajF\xE2\x80\xA6
```

here is another example:

```
2014\x0934447260\x09RBEKP\x090\x090\x09\xE2\x80\x9C@LENEsipper: Wild lmfaooo RT @Yerrp08: L**o some
 n***a nutt up while gettin twerked
```

I noted that `\x09` should be a tab character (ASCII 09 is tab), So I tried to use `apache Hex`:

```
    String tmp = value.toString();
    byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(tmp.toCharArray());
```

But the `decodeHex` function returns null.

This is weird, since some of the characters are in hex while others are not. How can I decode them?

Edit: 
Also note that besides `tab`, `emojis` are also encoded as hex values.